# Загрузка пользователя APEX скриптом

Tags: oracle-apex

Завести пользователя APEX можно вручную через INTERNAL/ADMIN, далее *Manage Workspaces -> Manage Developers and Users*.

Можно ли грузить пользователя не вручную, а скриптом?

Для чего нужно: существует продакш-сервер, который ежедневно клонируется на сервер для тестирования. Завести пользователя на продакшене, чтобы он приходил с клонированием, не позволяет безопасность. А заводить пользователей на клоне ежедневно вручную не очень удобно, хотелось бы автоматизировать процесс.

Comment: Не совсем понял. Для чего на тесте Вам нужны пользователи workspace? Авторизация в приложении?

Comment: Нужна авторизация разработчика в Апексе. 

С Прода приходит копия, где есть только INTERNAL/admin. Мне нужно добавить пользователя Апекс-разработчика. Сейчас я это делаю вручную, вхожу под админом и добавляю через _Manage Workspaces_ -> _Manage Developers and Users_ -> _Create User_. А хочется автоматизировать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хм... занимательная задача :-) Если я Вас правильно понял:

1. В тесте разворачивается копия **workspace** с включёнными в него **apex**-приложениями.
2. Из прода приходит копия **workspace** только с одним пользователем с доступом к разработке (**INTERNAL/admin**)

Вот [тут](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/how-to-script-workspace-provisioning-on-oracle-autonomous-database), мне кажется, Вы найдёте вот это:

```
apex_util.create_user(
        p_user_name                    => 'TEST1',
        p_web_password                 => '************',
        p_developer_privs              => 'ADMIN:CREATE:DATA_LOADER:EDIT:HELP:MONITOR:SQL',
        p_email_address                => 'test1@example.com',
        p_default_schema               => 'TEST1',
        p_change_password_on_first_use => 'N' );
```

В самой статье так же есть информация по скриптам, которые пригодятся при автоматизированном создании **workspace** с его начальными настройками. Надеюсь, я ответил на Ваш вопрос

Comment: _apex_util.create_user()_? Как я её пропустил-то? Вот спасибо, то что нужно! Статья тоже полезная, хотя в данный момент именно это мне не обязательно создавать, достаточно юзера. Но пригодится.

Comment: Уточнение: перед вызовом ```apex_util.create_user()``` нужно вызвать так же ```l_workspace_id := apex_util.find_security_group_id (p_workspace => '...')```: и ```apex_util.set_security_group_id (p_security_group_id => l_workspace_id)```;